# Neo4J without ServiceLoader

Tags: java, osgi, neo4j, serviceloader

I have been using `Neo4J 1.8.x` as an embedded database in an application framework that breaks the regular `ServiceLoader` used by `Neo4j`. So far, I've worked around this issue by using the [OSGi instructions for Neo4j](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.3/tutorials-java-embedded-osgi.html). This has worked great.

However, these `OSGi` instructions no longer work for `1.9.0`, `1.9.1` or `2.0.0-M03`. When initializing the embedded database I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at plugins.fritter.Fritter.setupNeo4j(Fritter.java:240)
at plugins.fritter.Fritter.runPlugin(Fritter.java:106)
at freenet.pluginmanager.PluginHandler.startPlugin(PluginHandler.java:45)
at freenet.pluginmanager.PluginManager.realStartPlugin(PluginManager.java:394)
at freenet.pluginmanager.PluginManager.startPluginFile(PluginManager.java:367)
at freenet.clients.http.PproxyToadlet$3.run(PproxyToadlet.java:157)
at freenet.support.PooledExecutor$MyThread.innerRun(PooledExecutor.java:247)
at freenet.support.PooledExecutor$MyThread.realRun(PooledExecutor.java:187)
at freenet.support.io.NativeThread.run(NativeThread.java:129)

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings.<clinit>(GraphDatabaseSettings.java:79)
... 9 more
```

I am aware that the `OSGi` setup instructions have changed from `1.9.0` and higher versions [OSGI](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/tutorials-java-embedded-osgi.html), but the new initialization methods do not address the issue.

Is `neo4j` > `1.8.3` still supported in a `non-ServiceLoader` / `OSGi` context and, if so, what is the proper way to set it up?

Comment: The service loading code has changed quite a bit in Neo4j 1.9 and above:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.9.1/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/helpers/Service.java

You aren't able to load a cache: 

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.9.1/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.java#L394

Though I don't know why.

Comment: Right it did change. It seems that the relevant code you are linking to still depends on a functional ServiceLoader and hence breaks in my plugin environment?

Comment: I'm guessing, yes. Have you tried the META-INF/services directory? It looks like you can bootstrap neo4j a standard way as long as you have your services directory in order, since neo4j will use ServiceLoader and ServiceLoader will look into META-INF/services/ folder. 

EDIT: Oh! Not sure if you are actually using OSGI or if your framework just breaks ServiceLoader. In the latter case, best bet may be to patch neo4j yourself (it's why I gave you the source code link =) ).

http://blog.osgi.org/2013/02/javautilserviceloader-in-osgi.html